# Extending Laravel/Lumen Query Builder to automagically add SQL comments

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-rds, lumen-5.8

I use a large RDS database instance that is shared among several different projects (not microservices to be exact) and this database's performance is critical. Hence I monitor the queries whenever support team raise tickets related to performance of our services. So in order for me to track where each query originated from i.e, which app, file and line number, I want to automatically add a SQL comment for all queries. So when I call toSql() on the query builder object it must show me the comment

```sql
-- lumen-api:app/Http/Controllers/APIController.php:85
select * from users;
```

```php
env(app_name) .  ':'. __FILE__  . ':' . __LINE__.
```

I tried to extend query builder and grammar classes and bind them to the service container but I think I'm doing something wrong. Please take a look at my implementation of how I extended those classes.

```php
<?php

// app/Classes/Database/Query/Grammars/QueryGrammar.php

namespace App\Classes\Database\Query\Grammars;

use App\Classes\Database\Query\QueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar;

class QueryGrammar extends Grammar
{
    /**
     * @param QueryBuilder $query
     * @param $comment
     * @return string
     */
    public function compileComment(QueryBuilder $query, $comment)
    {
        $this->selectComponents[] = 'comment';
        return '-- ' . $comment . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

// app/Classes/Database/Query/QueryBuilder.php

<?php

namespace App\Classes\Database\Query;

use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

class QueryBuilder extends Builder {

    /**
     * @param $comment
     * @return $this
     */
    public function comment($comment): QueryBuilder
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

//app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Classes\Database\Query\Grammars\QueryGrammar;
use App\Classes\Database\Query\QueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        /**
         * Extending Query Builder to support SQL comments
         */
        $this->app->bind(Grammar::class, function () {
            return new QueryGrammar();
        });

        $this->app->bind(Builder::class, function () {
            return new QueryBuilder(/* how to send params?*/);
        });

    }
}
```

I know this implementation is not for auto adding the sql comments. So when I use this in my controller:

`return Admin::where('login_email','bhargav.nanekalva@mpokket.com')->comment(__FILE__ . __LINE__)->toSql();`

Laravel throws the following error: (which means the binding didn't happen)

```
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::comment()
```

what I need help is for

- The right way to modify these classes
- automatically adding the sql comment

Comment: You want solution for Mysql?

Comment: @Vinay Sure anything will do. But just curious, why can't we have a generic solution that can work for any database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the Grammer class directly may be possible but it internally delegates its work to Database Specific grammer classes

For example if you have configured Mysql in config/database.php then the Grammer class delegates the work on to `Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar`

Similarly for Postgres it will be `Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\PostgresGrammar`

Based on the database config the
ConnectionFactory[`src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php->createConnection()`]

loads the proper connection manager for a given database

I am not sure if overriding of this classes is even possible or not because of the PSR-4 loading as the namespace is tightly linked with the physical location of the file in the directory tree

So instead of that I would suggest to go for laravel macros by which you may add new functions to existing classes that use [Macroable](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.html) trait

A POC example can be found below, for further advancement you are  encouraged to dig the code for update, insert, delete etc in Grammer.php and Builder.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        Grammar::macro("T_compileSelect", function (Builder $query) {
            if ($query->unions && $query->aggregate) {
                return $this->compileUnionAggregate($query);
            }

            $original = $query->columns;

            if (is_null($query->columns)) {
                $query->columns = ['*'];
            }

            $sql = trim($this->concatenate(
                $this->compileComponents($query))
            );

            if ($query->unions) {
                $sql = $this->wrapUnion($sql).' '.$this->compileUnions($query);
            }

            $query->columns = $original;

            return $sql . ' -- ' . (!empty($query->comment)?$query->comment:'');
        });

        Builder::macro("T_toSql", function () {
            $str = $this->grammar->T_compileSelect($this);
            return $str;
        });

        Builder::macro("T_runSelect", function () {
            $str =  $this->connection->select(
                $this->T_toSql(), $this->getBindings(), ! $this->useWritePdo
            );
            return $str;
        });

        Builder::macro("addComment", function ($comment, $columns = ['*']) {
            $this->comment = $comment;
            $res = collect($this->onceWithColumns(Arr::wrap($columns), function () {
                return  $this->processor->processSelect($this, $this->T_runSelect());
            }));
            return $res;
        });

    }

    public function boot()
    {
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
            Admin::where('login_email','bhargav.nanekalva@mpokket.com')
            ->addComment(__FILE__ . __LINE__)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this. BTW, have you tested this work?

Comment: can have this comment method automatically run without explicitly calling it?

Comment: Yes it will work since all the code in `register()` is directly pulled from `src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php` and `src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php` we just modify the the name for instance `T_compileSelect` instead of  original `compileSelect` to avoid collision

Comment: I accepted before testing it and it did actually work. Thanks! Also I would like to know how I can implicitly call this method without having the developer to call this method everywhere?

Comment: As such doesn't look possible, may be we can subclass the core Eloquents Model class and then inherit your Admin model from it so you can manipulate what code gets behind the scenes on executing  ->get(), ->insert(), ->update(). via `__callStatic()` magic method but again not worth the effort I guess

Comment: Thanks for providing valuable insights! @Vinay

Comment: just an update: sorry the comment is not getting added to the query as I checked with toSql(). Can you please verify from your side as well?